# Table belongs to which user

Tags: sql, database, oracle

In oracle...How can I know my table 'A' is belongs to which user !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query it's work with me

```
select table_name,owner from all_tables where table_name like '%CONTINENT%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM All_Objects
WHERE object_name = 'Your_table'
AND object_type = 'TABLE';
```

you could also query all_tables

```
SELECT * 
FROM all_tables
WHERE Table_name = 'Your_table'
```

[All tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2105.htm) shows the tables accessible to your user. DBA_tables shows all the tables in the database but requires elevated permissions usually associated with the DBA role.

Comment: when I use your first query it display an error like
Erreur commençant à la ligne: 19 de la commande -
FROM All_Objects
Rapport d'erreur -
Commande inconnue


Erreur commençant à la ligne: 20 de la commande -
WHERE object_name = 'CONTINENT'
Rapport d'erreur -
Commande inconnue


Erreur commençant à la ligne: 21 de la commande -
AND object_type = 'TABLE'
Rapport d'erreur -
Commande inconnue

Comment: @Abderrahim please show the exact statement you are running and what Oracle version.  What privileges do you have? regular user or DBA?

Comment: When I use your second query. Although I have this table in my database it displays there is no row

Comment: the exact statement is 
FROM All_Objects
WHERE object_name = 'CONTINENT'
AND object_type = 'TABLE';

Comment: @Abderrahim: You forgot the `SELECT *` before the `FROM`.

Comment: yes you're right @sstan but you check my answer it's work with me

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  select owner from dba_tables where table_name ='TAB1'
```

Comment: Take a look at what it displays as an error
Erreur commençant à la ligne: 19 de la commande -
select owner from dba_tables where table_name ='CONTINENT'
Erreur à la ligne de commande: 19 Colonne: 19
Rapport d'erreur -
Erreur SQL : ORA-00942: Table ou vue inexistante
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: It does appear that Abderrahim has DBA role permissions.